# Regrouping in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using views in sql server in order to get reports about purchase.

So I have created two views:

1. DETAIL_TRANSFERT
2. DETAIL_PURCHASE
3. TOTAL_COST: UNION of DETAIL_TRANSFERT AND DETAIL_PURCHASE

My problem is : In DETAIL_PURCHASE I have a repeated identical lines like :

```
EXAMPLE: 
LIGNE1
Piece: 1
PRICE: 2.5
CATEGRIE:PURCH
LIGNE2:
Piece: 1
PRICE: 2.5 
CATEGRIE:PURCH
```

SUM (price) in DETAIL_PURCHASE= 5 but in TOTAL_COST the second ligne is ignored and the  SUM (price)=2.5

Comment: Your question risks being downvoted/closed due to a lack of clarity in your question. Please consider rewording to make it more clear what you are asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any further details, it sounds like in your TOTAL_COST view you need to use UNION ALL instead of UNION. If ALL is not specified then duplicate rows are removed by default. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) for more details.